# Should mixed-model and multilevel-analysis be tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tags [mixed-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model) and [multilevel-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilevel-analysis) seem to be entirely redundant upon a quick glance at the question lists. Should we only have one tag? (I'm not quite sure what the difference between tag synonyms and merging tags are.)

Comment: Maybe we can add [mixed-effects-model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-effects-model) to that list as well.

Comment: Let's define first what you or others understand as mixed *vs.* multilevel models. (There are many definitions and theoretical approaches to such models, but some may also argue this is just reflecting a terminological issue.) If it happens that they refer to different modeling strategies or contexts of use, then it might be best to create synonyms. That being said, I agree that 'mixed-model' and 'mixed-effects-model' should be merged.

Comment: @chl , I would personally define multilevel models exactly how mixed-models are defined in its tag wiki. I come across the terminology "mixed" far less frequently than "multilevel" or "hierarchical", so I'm less comfortable defining how "mixed" is used in practice. Like I stated previously there doesn't appear to be any difference in the nature of the questions that uses each tag that I can discern from a quick glance of the list.

Comment: An example of what I had in mind when writing my comment: I would consider that a within-subject design in a psychological experiment (repeated measures are collected on the same statistical unit, with potential crossed factors and/or one or more between-subject factor) falls under the mixed-model approach; in contrast, students nested within schools nested within counties or countries falls under the multilevel or hierarchical approach. I agree this is pure terminology. Doug Bates or JK Lindsey provided more detailed explanations.

Comment: @chl , I agree that is consistent with what I have encountered (casually I would say I only see mixed used in reference to repeated measures designs like in your example). Perhaps updating the tag wikis would suffice.

Comment: Well, I'm just reading the tag wikis :-) You're right, we need to think of refining them (I can even use a mixed-effect model to estimate an intra-class correlation coefficient :-)

Comment: FYI, I merged the 'mixed-model' and 'mixed-effects-model' tags. (/cc @whuber @mbq)

Comment: I cannot find the "mixed-effects-model" tag now, and "'mixed-model' currently has no approved synonyms". Maybe we can merge "mixed-model" and "mixed-effect" tags?

Comment: @Randel - that seems reasonable to me, also see the [mixed](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed) tag that should likely be consolidated. Feel free to either give an answer or edit my question so it gets bumped to the top. If you don't do this I will edit when I get a chance.

Comment: +1. I am also curious about the difference between tag synonyms and merging tags. Or @chl has deleted the "mixed-effects-model" tag?

Comment: @Randel I probably only merged the two tags, without making any synonym. (Usually when merging, an old tag is replaced with a new one; it is possible to make the old tag a synonym when doing this.) I agree with you: the [tag:mixed-model] and [tag:mixed-effect] tags should probably be merged.