# What should we do about the [hierarchical] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

*(Note this previous, related discussion: [Redundant tags: mixed effects and related models](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1369/7290).)*

The [hierarchical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical) tag is very ambiguous.  Unfortunately, this hasn't been addressed before and it now has 142 questions.  An excerpt was just suggested:

> For questions about hierarchical models, also called multi-level models.

However, it isn't at all clear that that's what the threads grouped under this tag are about.  (It isn't clear they are consistently about anything.)  For example, [at least 33 are about clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhierarchical%5D%20clustering%20is%3Aquestion).

I'm wondering what we should do about this.  It really seems to be a mess.  Some options might be: retagging, making synonyms and/or merging, or deleting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have several well-established tags that start with "hierarchical":

- [hierarchical-bayesian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical-bayesian) × 278
- [hierarchical-clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical-clustering) × 184
- [hierarchical-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical-analysis) $\to$ [multilevel-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilevel-analysis) × 783

In this situation having a generic [hierarchical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical) tag is just plain confusing; everybody is supposed to be picking one of the more specific tags instead of using the obviously ambiguous generic one. So we should eliminate it.

It would probably require going through all 142 questions and retagging as appropriate. As always, we can manually retag only questions that are *not* about multilevel-analysis (based on the numbers above, this seems to be the most common usage). After this is done, the rest can be moved to `multilevel-analysis` via mod action (to save some time & to minimize flooding the front page).

**Update (Nov 1, 2017): This has been finished, and the tag is gone.**

Comment: Yeah, I was worried it might have to come down to going through all 142. I did just start retagging some that should obviously be `[hierarchical-clustering]` instead of `[clustering]` `[hierarchical]`.

Comment: If I were to retag these ones, I would leave [clustering] tag (and replace [hierarchical] with [hierarchical-clustering]); it's an old discussion about hierarchical tags (pun intended), but I find it useful e.g. to have clustering-related threads under [clustering] even if there is a more narrow tag. This is not very important though.

Comment: OK, so what I'm doing now is reading to see if each question is really only about the peculiarities of hierarchical clustering, or if it is about HC as an instance of clustering generally. I then tag w/ HC alone, or w/ both. In general, I'm not a fan of having to use 2 nested tags.

Comment: I found 8 that had "Bayesian" in them. Those have now been done.

Comment: All the threads from the search on "clustering" have now been edited. There are 99 <strike>[red balloons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4kEm8XECLQ)</strike> threads left.

Comment: I guess all of them can be moved to multilevel-analysis now? Or do you want to go over them first to double-check? By the way, I edited the wiki excerpt & wiki of multilevel-analysis. I was hesitating about what to do with [nested-data] (that I created out of [nested] just some days ago) vs. [multilevel-analysis], but maybe it makes sense to leave them be as is. These concepts are strongly intersecting though. In fact, multilevel-analysis is somewhat vague.

Comment: Multilevel-analysis is somewhat vague. We can deal w/ that later, I suppose. I'm not sure if the rest can be merged now; I'm not sure if they are really all about MLA--I haven't yet gone through them to check. I've only done the ones that can be captured through simple, intuitive searches.

Comment: I still haven't gone through the remaining tags, but I'm not sure when I will. Do you think we should just go ahead and move them to multilevel-analysis now? What do you suggest?

Comment: @gung The last time we talked about it I took a brief a look at the remaining questions and had the feeling that there is some non-negligible fraction that are not really about multilevel analysis. So ideally I'd say we should look through them and remove [hierarchical] from everywhere where multivelel-analysis would be a misnomer. This would also make the case for the subsequent move stronger. But I did not come around doing it so far...

Comment: @gung I think this search https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical+-regression+-multiple-regression+-multilevel-analysis+-mixed-model shows the threads that we should take a look at (and in many cases it seems remove the [hierarchical] tag), there is currently 40 of them.

Comment: FYI: I started going over the search results in my last comment above (42 of them at the moment) and am planning to retag all that are *not* about [multilevel-analysis]. After this is done, I think we can proceed with the merge as planned.

Comment: was our plan to make `[hierarchical]` a synonym of `[multilevel-analysis]`? (It would seem so...) I agree w/ your point that `h` is a bad tag to have around. If we make it a synonym, it will still show up when people start typing "hier" (I believe this is true even if merged). I wonder if retagging as `m-a` is better in the long run.

Comment: @gung Can't you (i) make the synonym, (ii) merge, (iii) delete the synonym mapping?

Comment: I don't know. I can try to find out.

Comment: @gung I did not realize that it's not clear if this is possible. Somehow I thought this should be doable, but I don't really know. I guess we can just try. I will ping you when I go through the remaining threads.

Comment: Just b/c I don't know doesn't mean it's not possible ;-). I'll have to try to find out. This should be a surmountable obstacle one way or another.

Comment: I think I can do it. Let's just go ahead & we'll make it work. Let me know when you're finished.

Comment: I am done. I removed the tag from some threads, and all the remaining ones can be moved to multilevel-analysis. Let me know if it works out.

Comment: It seems to have worked. The questions all have `[multilevel-analysis]` now, & `[hierarchical]` is just gone entirely.