# Let us merge [mixed], [mixed-effect] and [mixed-model] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Recently I have been reading quite a lot on CV about fixed / random / mixed effects models and related terminological controversies. Unfortunately, the CV tags for the mixed models are a mess, which does not help navigating the questions (which is a pity, given that the topic is confusing enough).

Namely, there is [mixed-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model) tag (<strike>689</strike> 1214 questions, nice wiki),  [mixed-effect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-effect) tag (<strike>95</strike> 305 questions, worse wiki), and also [mixed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed) tag (<strike>28</strike> 61 questions, no wiki). I do know that terms *fixed* and *random* are used differently by different people, but as far as I understand, mixed is mixed. So I think these three tags should be merged.

**I think the master tag should be [mixed-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model), and the other two can be merged into it.**

The two related tags are called [random-effects-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-effects-model) and [fixed-effects-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-effects-model), so originally I wrote here that the best name for the merged tag would be `[mixed-effects-model]` (which currently does not exist at all); however, on reflection, "mixed model" [seems to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) a more standard terminology.

---

This issue was brought up multiple times on Meta, but stays unresolved.

- [Here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/current-tag-synonym-candidates/1969) I suggested the same thing yesterday and @gung commented that it seems reasonable.
- In 2012 [a bunch of related tags](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/redundant-tags-mixed-effects-and-related-models) was discussed with the same suggestion about "mixed" tags, and I can see no counter-arguments in the discussion (even in the careful reply of @StasK).
- In 2011 [a related question was asked](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/890/should-mixed-model-and-multilevel-analysis-be-tag-synonyms), and @chl reported in the comments that he merged [mixed-model] and [mixed-effects-model] (the latter tag does not exist anymore).
- In 2013 @Randel left a comment in the above thread suggesting the same thing as I do here, and @AndyW and @chl agreed.

Comment: Agree. In a similar vein, suggest that `multilevel` (even  `hierarchical`) should be lumped in the `mixed effects` tag. For a beginner I think the former terms make things easier to understand, whereas the `fixed/random` terminology can be a bit off-putting at first.

Comment: @dardisco: Personally, I tend to agree, but note that yours is a much more contentious suggestion, see e.g. StasK's answer [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/redundant-tags-mixed-effects-and-related-models).

Comment: Sensible suggestion. I'd vote to merge into 'mixed-effect'. I think this just reflects the different terminology in circulation more widely.

Comment: @whuber: Now that I reached 1k rep, I can see that this question was upvoted 16 times and never downvoted. To me it looks like a consensus, but the tags are still not merged. What is actually the procedure (if any)? Is there a certain number of upvotes that has to be reached? I am sorry to bother you about that, but I noticed that most of the recent tag synonyms were declared by you.

Comment: Any ideas on merging the tag wikis? [tag:mixed-model] is good but, oddly, doesn't make any mention of fixed vs random, like [tag:mixed-effects] does.

Comment: I will try to merge the wikis, @Scortchi. However, I should say that even though I appear here as the main proponent of this tag merge, I am actually not really familiar with mixed models and my knowledge of econometrics is zero; so this terminology and the differences in definitions confuse me. I am sure many other users here could contribute a much more meaningful wiki edit...

Comment: Well at any rate it's better not to lose previous efforts & it can always be improved in future.

Comment: I wonder if we can recruit someone to assist with this before we merge the tags. There really is a difference between the way the names are used in econometrics vs more canonical statistics terminology. (cc @Scortchi)

Comment: @gung, I have taken a careful look at the two wikis, and figured that I can merge them reasonably well. I did it now. Almost no text has been lost, I just copy-pasted and rearranged it (and adapted the excerpt). Just in case, I posted both tag wikis as they were before my edits as an answer here, and then deleted my answer; I believe both you and Scortchi can see the deleted answer. The wiki might not be perfect and it might be a good idea to ask somebody to take a look at it, but **I think we can go ahead with the tag merge nevertheless.** The wiki can always be edited later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mixed-effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-effects) & [mixed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed) are now synonyms of [mixed-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model) (the master tag).