# Should we do something about [mixed-design] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-reorganization

I noticed that we have [mixed-design](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-design)×63 tag that did not have any wiki excerpt. Many of the questions are about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-design_analysis_of_variance, i.e. ANOVA analysis with between-subject and within-subject factors. But a noticeable fraction of the questions is about mixed models, or about something else entirely. And indeed the term "mixed design" refers to experimental design and so in a way is very broad, encompassing large fraction of the mixed model questions. I don't think this is a productive tag.

My suggestion is to go through all [mixed-design] Qs, remove the ones that are not about mixed ANOVA, then rename the tag into [mixed-anova], and then make it a synonym of [anova](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anova). The idea is that in the end we have [anova](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anova) and [mixed-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model), and Qs about mixed ANOVA should go into [anova].

Alternatively, we *could* have [mixed-anova](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-anova) as a separate tag, but currently there are [hundreds Qs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Banova%5D+mixed+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bmixed-design%5D) about mixed ANOVA not tagged as such, so I'd say it's too late.

An additional complication is that we also have a [split-plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/split-plot)×53 tag which is basically the same thing, but is more of a niche terminology. My inclination would be to leave it as is. Current wiki excerpt:

> An experimental design used in situations where one factor can be changed more easily than another one. It's also called "mixed design" because it involves between-subject (hard to change) and within-subject (aka repeated measures; easy to change) factors.

PS. This is a continuation of [Let us merge [mixed], [mixed-effect] and [mixed-model] tags](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1970).

Comment: It seems the tag was created in July 2014 for [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105873) question about mixed ANOVA.

Comment: It's a tricky situation, but your proposal seems at least as reasonable as anything else I could think of. The biggest catch I can think of is that, while in practice [tag:mixed-design] seems to mostly be used to talk about mixed ANOVA, in theory I think the tag might more appropriately be a synonym for [tag:split-plot]. But I guess there's no sense in creating a synonym that would be contrary to how most users actually end up applying [tag:mixed-design] to their questions.

Comment: @Jake that's right, that's partly why I suggest to eliminate [mixed-design] as a tag name; if we rename it into [mixed-anova] and make it a synonym of [anova], anybody wanting to ask about mixed anova will correctly get redirected to [anova]. I doubt that with this arrangement, [mixed-design] will ever reappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have eliminated [mixed-design](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-design).

Questions about mixed ANOVA I was retagging as newly created [mixed-anova](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-anova); as a result this tag now has ~40 threads.

As I wrote in the question, given that [anova](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anova) already has *hundreds* of questions about mixed ANOVA (any ANOVA analysis involving some within-subject and some between-subject effects) , I suggest we make `[mixed-anova]` a synonym of `[anova]` now.

I have suggested this synonym so upvote if you agree: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/anova/synonyms.

Comment: I think this is a nice solution. Removing `mixed-design`, which can mean a lot of things not necessarily related to anova, makes a lot of sense. And I also agree that `mixed-anova` can just link to anova. Thanks.

Comment: I [believe I] approved the synonym for this & merged them. [Something is strange, though, & I can't tell if it worked properly. Hopefully, it's done & the issue is permanently resolved.]

Comment: @gung Looks merged to me. Thanks! Answer marked as accepted.

Comment: @gung Hmm, I wonder if whatever "was strange" could have caused this: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5186.

Comment: Yeah, could be. At this point, I don't quite remember what the issue was, though. Maybe the m-a 'ghost' is a one-off, & not something that will typically occur. If so, just fixing the m-a ghost via a hack should be doable.

Comment: @gung Hmm, I tried to delete or edit https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/324506/edit, but I am getting "An error occured submitting the edit" error message no matter what edit I am trying to do (either deleting the whole excerpt or replacing it with something). Could you try to delete it as a mod?

Comment: I can't tell that it worked for me, either. I can just delete [m-a] altogether. Do you want me to do that? (I could also try to recreate it later as a synonym.)

Comment: @gung I just noticed that I don't see the ghost excerpt on the Tags page anymore (even though if I open https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/324506/edit, then I still see it, but now it does not seem to be displayed anywhere). I am wondering if you did anything else since then or if the problem just dissolved somehow.

Comment: I don't quite remember, @amoeba. I thought I deleted the tag altogether. I'm pretty sure I remember doing that. But it's clearly still there. I think the link to the edit page is just flotsam in the servers for the site that no one has ever thought to clean up (& may not be worth the devs' time). My guess is that at this point the situation has resolved itself satisfactorily one way or another.